# Delete and update data in database and refresh datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I use this code to delete from database any record I want

```
string cs = "Data Source=CODRINMA\\CODRINMA;Initial Catalog=BusManager; Trusted_Connection=True;";

string delete = "DELETE FROM Autogari WHERE IDAutogara=@IDAutogara";

try
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(delete, con);
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDAutogara", int.Parse(grdAutogari.CurrentRow.Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString()));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Autogara a fost stearsa cu succes!");
        con.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception er) { MessageBox.Show(er.Message); }
```

But, at the same time I would like that the `DataGridView` to refresh it automatically (the deleted record to disappear), which is not happening. What am I missing?

Comment: Try a `Gridviewname.Databind()` after deleting

Comment: If you want your grid to reflect changes in the database you have to rebind it. It isn't going to do it by itself. You might consider adding some logging in your catch. As it stands the only person who knows something happened is the user which doesn't put you in a great position to even know an error happened, let alone fix it. Also I would recommend you take a look at this article. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Call gridview function after deleting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the query again, not the delete query but the select * query to fill or "refresh" your datagridview after you deleted the row.